# Where is the "Search" place in the file open dialog?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, dialog

I remember that in earlier versions of Ubuntu there was a "search" place in the file open dialog (for example like the one in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9z7G.png)).

However in Ubuntu 14.04, I don't see it anymore:

[image: no more _search_ place in the file open dialog]

Is it just gone, or is there an option somewhere?

thank you,
- Michele

Answer (score 0):

Activate the file list (for example by single-clicking into it) and start typing.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options to search for files inside the open dialog window:

1. Click on the pencil [image] and start typing in the location text field:

   [image]
2. Click on the list on files (a file should get the focus) and again start typing to see the Search field (bottom-right corner):

   [image]

---

**Update**

Gedit seems to have its own gtk widget for the open dialog but both methods are still valid:

[image]

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't do the same. In the screenshots you posted, you have the _old_ dialog. I still have the old dialog when I try opening a file from Firefox, but when I do the same from gedit I get the new one that I pictured in the question.

Could you please try doing the same from gedit. I am wondering whether this is just some wrong setting on my side.

Comment: @Michele you didn't mention Gedit in your question but I can confirm that even if the look is a bit different, both methods still work (see the above screenshot).

Comment: I don't think that Gedit has its own widget for the open dialog. It seems more to be the most recent dialog from Gnome:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html

Comment: In your example, you are looking for a file that is within the current folder. I would like to be able to search for files that are somewhere else on my computer.


I am afraid that Gnome people removed it, or put it in a way that is hardly used outside of Gnome-Shell environment.


In any case, many thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint (hope it's the same in Ubuntu), when you just click on a folder in the folder plane and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, a search dialog will open. Then you have to *click* on it, before starting to type.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/944151/390262